# Criar Trigger após o insert com condição

Tags: php, mysql, sql, trigger

Bom dia,
Pessoal eu tenho a seguinte tabela no mysql no meu sistema financeiro

```
    CREATE TABLE `lancamentos` (
  `lcto_id` int NOT NULL,
  `lcto_id_contas` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `lcto_id_tipo` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `lcto_id_categorias` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `lcto_valor` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lcto_dt_lcto` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `lcto_dt_vcto` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `lcto_id_situacao` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `lcto_anexo` longblob,
  `lcto_tipo_anexo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lcto_nome_anexo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lcto_descricao` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lcto_import` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

O problema está nos lançamentos de transferencias, que eu tenho o campo Origem e o campo Destino, então preciso incluir um evento depois do insert quando o lcto_id_tipo for igual a 1 (transferencia), onde ele inclui o lançamento de entrada (+) na conta destino. Como eu posso estar fazendo isso com a Trigger, ou outro recurso no mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar através deste formato:

```
DELIMITER $
 
CREATE TRIGGER nome_da_trigger AFTER/BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE ON nome_da_tabela
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
-- sua query aqui terminando com ponto-e-vírgula
END $
 
DELIMITER ;

Exemplo:

DELIMITER $

CREATE TRIGGER nome_da_trigger BEFORE INSERT
ON nome_da_tabela
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    -- Nesta parte a instrução SQL correspondente 

END$
```

Segue um exemplo de trigger no MySql:

```
CREATE TABLE Produtos
(
    Referencia  VARCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    Descricao   VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
    Estoque INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE ItensVenda
(
    Venda       INT,
    Produto VARCHAR(3),
    Quantidade  INT
);
    

DELIMITER $

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_exemplo BEFORE INSERT
ON ItensVenda
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    
    IF(NEW.Venda = 5) THEN
        UPDATE Produtos SET Estoque = Estoque - NEW.Quantidade
        WHERE Referencia = NEW.Produto;
    ELSE
        -- Instrução SQL
    END IF;

END$

DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO ItensVenda VALUES (5, '003',2);
```